# EKCalendar remains in calendar app after deleting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

I am working on an application that uses EKEventStore and EKCalendar.

The EKEventStore is a static:

```
static EKEventStore *eventStore = nil;
```

I then use the following method to see if the user allows me access to their calendar.

```
- (void)requestAccess:(void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error))callback;
{
    if (eventStore == nil) {
        eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    }
    // request permissions
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:callback];

    //EKCalendar *calendar = nil;
     NSString *calendarIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:calendarIdentifer];
    if (calendarIdentifier) {
        self.calendar = [self retrieveCalendar];
    }

}
```

After this I am able to create a new calendar and save my event. However if I delete the application the calendar remains in the calendar app. When I run the app I am creating a new EKEventStore and that means I am also creating a new calendar.

This means that if I delete the app and reinstall multiple times I end up with a huge list of the same calendars with only the newest being accessible to me in the app. Is it possible to delete the calendar when the app is deleted. Or is there something I can do to access the previous calendar that was created.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Until now i didn't found other solution so:
to get your previous calendar you can search by name like this:

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSArray *calendarEvents = [eventDB calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
NSArray *calendarReminder = [eventDB calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];

NSMutableArray *calendars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:calendarEvents];
[calendars addObjectsFromArray:calendarReminder];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *typeString = @"";

for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in calendars) 
    if([thisCalendar.title isEqualToString:@"YourcalendarName"])
        // your code
```

but user can change the calendar name and this is risky, so you can get it buy the id that you can store when you create the calendar, BUT if you merge with iCloud:

> A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetch-able by caching its other properties.